# Defining a metric that quantitatively assesses two sets of data for similarity

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, correlation, equivalent-metrics

I have two sets of data where the x values are identical in both sets.

I am trying to determine a quantitative metric to determine how similar the two plots are in terms of shape of the graph, i.e I dont care about the magnitudes of values but the overall shape and trends of the graph.

I recorded the driving of two different people in a vehicle from point A to point B and I am trying to quantify where similarities or differences exist between both driver's speed profiles along the path, such as how they entered a turn and exited a turn, (driver A tends to break earlier before approaching the apex and driver B tends to hold its speed around the curve rather then let it bleed off a bit)

I have an ideal path and id like to say Driver A was closer to that than Driver B. Are there any statistical inference tools I can use in this situation?
[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn3RZ.png)

Blue is Driver A, Orange is Driver B and red is the optimal path.

Comment: For clarification: do you have a curve $C$ and want to measure how similar two functions $f,g:C\to \mathbb R^n$ on that curve are?

Comment: I added an image in the OP that has  both sets of data and the optimal path plotted. The plot clearly illustrates similar trends, and where differences occur. Again, I do not care about magnitudes so I can normalize them from 0,1. I am trying to character the behavior orange has around 90 with the divits, and how neither of the other plots contain that.

Comment: if you can rescale the blue and orange curves arbitrarily, why don't minimizes $\| \alpha f_{blue} - f_{red} \|$ for some scalar $\alpha$ and in whatever norm $\|\cdot\|$ you like?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I did not understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: Various methods have been used to 'measure' the distance between curves. Without math notation, here are a couple: (a) The largest vertical distance between the curves. (b) The area between the curves. By either criterion (a) or (b), orange is closer to red than blue is.